# Linux shell lagging one step

Tags: linux, busybox, minicom

I upgraded busybox from 1.2.1 to 1.7.4 in my embedded system platform and it is connected to linux host via serial cable. Now when I type any command in shell on that embedded system platform like `ifconfig` it is showing as `ifconfi` only and when I press enter then it show `ifconfig` and again on pressing any key it is showing output of `ifconfig`.

I am not sure if it is carriage return problem or stdout buffering issue. Also during boot up of platform it is stops after executing a few scripts and on pressing any key it continues the boot up process.

I got stuck there badly, any suggestions?

Comment: This seems pretty likely to be two separate problems, so you probably want to split this question in two (one for each issue you are facing).

Comment: Please describe more detailed what is happening during boot: on which scripts got freeze, is there any prompt, waiting for your interaction and so on.

Comment: I upgraded busybox from 1.2.1 to 1.17.4.
There are many scripts around 30 related to firewall,vpn, etc which are getting executed during bootup and it is getting stopped on any random script and after pressing enter it carry on the bootup process.